# How to encrypt stored inbox email messages

Tags: email, encryption, pgp

I have over 12000 email messages in my INBOX that are all in plain text, some of those email messages are with attachments. I have been searching for weeks on a way to encrypt those email messages from plain text to encrypted messages.

Please don't suggest PGP encryption for outgoing mails as I am fully aware of how to encrypt new composed messages. I am talking here about existing emails that are stored in the inbox for years in plain text.

I'm looking for a way that let me to encrypt them in bulk. I have downloaded all my messages and I have exported them to EML format, and I can convert them to any format that will assist me to encrypt those messages.

Looking to encrypt message body only and not subject.

Thank you

Comment: Doe - Well then I suppose you could take EML file and then PGP encrypt those with PGP file-level encryption with a public key, and then upload them. Once you access these and download from another system in the PGP encrypted format, you then PGP decrypt the files with your PGP private key that matches the public key you encrypted them with. I'm not sure you can take a FILE and only encrypt part of it. If it's EML, or MSG, or PST or whatever, it's going to be a file that needs to be encrypted so I'd looking for a file encryption method that will suffice e.g. PGP, GPG, ZIP, etc....

Comment: Because I want to upload those emails once again to online server so I can access them from anywhere via web browser or email client on computer or phone that supports PGP. and as I said I can convert those emails to any format not just EML!

Comment: The format will not matter, please read my new comment above; a file is a file, you need to encrypt the file before you upload it regardless of the format of that file. Just encrypt the EML or whatever FILE you format these flat files to that contain the email content with an encryption you can use before uploading. Once downloaded from the online server, you then decrypt the messages with file-level encryption. If you're using a system that supports other encryption methods, then you'd need to read up on that and it's configuration otherwise use FILE LEVEL ENCRYPTION for your files.

Comment: I also wanted to point out something, if the upload supports SSL connections, then upload via an SSL to the server and the data-in-transit will be secured going across the Internet on the upload. Is the concern with the clear text data being exposed while in transit from client to server or server to client or once accessed on the client and decrypted where that data is stored in cache, temp file, etc. in clear text? There are many way to accomplish what you ask but understanding at what level to encrypt the data may be important though for the final solution.

Comment: There is a bit of misunderstanding here. You said File is A File, and you asked me to just encrypt EML file, there are two issues that I have already addressed in my post above: 1- I have over 12000 EML file that I need to encrypt each individually which is impossible to do it manually. 2- each EML file includes email header, subject , message body and attachments. I need to encrypt message body and attachments ONLY. Also as mentioned that I'll upload those emails to sever so I can access them over WEBMAIL not email client and that makes huge difference to the whole thing!!!

Comment: So what I need is a software(s) that can Encrypt all my 12000 EML files all automatically and each message should be encrypted individually (body + Attachments) ONLY. To make this more clear, I am not worry at all about transit connection as I am fully able to secure that part which is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a good working solution today.

It is based on a procmail setting I found. It originally encrypts incoming mail instead of existing mails that are already in your inbox:

https://www.j3e.de/pgp-mime-encrypt-in-procmail.html (Thanks for this Bjoern)

I modified it to work as a script with existing Mailbox files instead of procmail (incoming files).

These commands are small, simple and use a standard tool 'formail' to handle headers and body cleanly.

First you have to create the two .gpg-mime-start and .gpg-mime-end files as descriped in the URL with procmail! And you have to set up your command line gpg with your keys as usual.

This is the .gpg-mime-start file:

```
--MfFXiAuoTsnnDAfX
Content-Type: application/pgp-encrypted
Content-Disposition: attachment

Version: 1

--MfFXiAuoTsnnDAfX
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="msg.asc"
```

There has to be an empty line at the end!

This is the .gpg-mime-end file:

```
--MfFXiAuoTsnnDAfX
```

There has to be an empty line at the beginning!

Here is the modified script (gpgmailfile.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

MYHDRS=`cat $1 | formail -XContent-Type: -XContent-disposition: -XContent-transfer-encoding:`

cat $1 | formail -X "" | formail -I 'Content-Type: multipart/encrypted; protocol="application/pgp-encrypted";boundary="MfFXiAuoTsnnDAfX"' -I Content-transfer-encoding: -I Content-disposition:

{ cat ~/.gpg-mime-start ; { echo "$MYHDRS" ; echo ; cat $1 | formail -I "" ; } | gpg --batch --quiet --always-trust -a -e -R 'Firstname Lastname <you@yourmail.com>' ; cat ~/.gpg-mime-end; }
```

Replace...

```
Firstname Lastname <you@yourmail.com>
```

...in the script with your gpg key address (or use "-r signature.." ).

Set permissions of the script with chmod a+x gpgmailfile.sh

For example you can run the script for a single mail from the main mail folder to the "enc" sub folder (first create "enc" folder in your email client):

```
./gpgmailfile.sh /home/user/Maildir/cur/"file123" > /home/user/Maildir/.enc/cur/"file123"
```

If you want to encrypt all mails in the main folder, use this extra script (change path to first script if not under /root/):

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES=/home/user/Maildir/cur/
cd $FILES
for f in *
do
  echo "Processing $f ..."
  /root/gpgmailfile.sh /home/user/Maildir/cur/"$f" > /home/user/Maildir/.enc/cur/"$f"
done
```

Modify it to work with other folders.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution encrypt the entire message itself instead of just the message body as per the author wanted?

Comment: It encrypts just the body. In Thunderbird I can decrypt the message with Enigmail. In another client without decryption feature I can see subject and sender but the body is encrypted.